# i didn't understand this code can anyone explain:

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand this code can anyone explain:

```
const statDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a boolean (true or false) based on a number of conditions.

If the startDate variable is not a number, it’ll return true,  otherwise that first part of the condition will evaluate to false, in which case it’ll continue to the part after the ||

So if startDate IS a number, then it will return either true or false based on the second clause in the condition (expense.createdAt >= startDate)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are using the OR operator `||` we are saying if ANY one of the conditions is true then `startDateMatch` will be true otherwise if will be false.

So on the left side of the OR we have `typeof startDate !== 'number'` which asks ... is the type of the variable `startDate` NOT equal to the string `number`. Lets call the result of this **A**.

On the right side we have `expense.createdAt >= startDate` which asks ... is the value of the variable `expense.createdAt` greater or equal to the value of the `startDate`. The result of this we will call **B**.

So on the end we are saying is that if ANY one of the results from A or B is true then assign that to the constant `startDateMatch`. If none of them is true well then `startDateMatch` will be false.

```
const startDateMatch is equal to: Is any one of the results from A and B true?
```

Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

/*first to judge whether the startDate's type is'number'; if not return true, if the startDate's 'number' then judge the condition  after the || */var flag= function(){if(typeof startDate !== 'number' ){  flag = true;}else if(expense.createdAt  >= startDate ){ return true;}else{ return false;}}const statDateMatch = flag()

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to explain what this code does and determine if it's correct or not, without having **context** of the code block. It's a good practice if you provide further details on **what** are you willing to achieve, and **how** anyone else could help.

However, given this single line this is what I would read in my head:

```
const statDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
^                   ^ ^                             ^  ^
|                   | |                             |  |
|                   | |                             |  |
|                   | |                             |  +-- the expense was created AFTER startDate ?
|                   | |                             |
|                   | |                             +--- or
|                   | |
|                   | +-- Is the type of startDate different than the string 'number' ?
|                   |
|                   +---- Assign the following expression once evaluated
|
+---- Declare a constant called "statDateMatch" (maybe typo here ??)
```

So read in *plain english* would be something like:

> *Is startDate different than a number or the expense creation date is after the start date? then consider it a statDateMatch*

**IMPORTANT**: Note that if `statDateMatch` was intented to be `startDateMatch`, a typo as simple as that might bring a lot of trouble trying to understand what the whole code block does for the faraway reader.